# How to make a writable Ubuntu installation USB?

Tags: system-installation, live-usb

I used MultiWriter to create an Ubuntu installation USB from the file:
ubuntustudio-20.04.4-dvd-amd64.iso

There is a modification I want to do to these files before they are used to do an installation. But I do not have write permissions on the ISO 9660 formatted USB. Is there a way make this USB writable? Is there a way to create a USB installation USB this is writable?

What the modifications I seek to do are described here:
https://www.reddit.com/r/pop_os/comments/p1nci7/pop_os_2104_zfs_on_root_install/
This requires a modification to the installation files. I cannot now do this. Can it be done with Cubic, or schroot?

Comment: Some people have had success using Cubic: https://launchpad.net/cubic

Comment: I find just running a script to make the changes I want, after the install to be easier. I can use same script across many versions, only some have needed minor changes.

Comment: Nmath: It does not answer it. I am not able to make any changes to the USB the ISO was installed in. That includes the inability to make directories, or copy files into it. So I cannot follow the directions in that link.